# How to use psycopg2 in AWS lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I'm getting the following error when trying to run psycopg2 in a AWS Lambda:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: authentication method 10 not supported
```

I tried to build from scratch, as in https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2, but still having the same error.

Can someone help me with it?

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(port=5432,database=xxxxx,user=XXXX,password=xxxxx)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cur= conn.cursor()
    XXXXX
```

Comment: Are you wanting to use `psycopg2` to connect with Amazon Redshift. If so, you might consider using the new Redshift Data API instead: [Announcing Data API for Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/announcing-data-api-for-amazon-redshift/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I would like to use Lambda to connect to Postgres on-premises in this case. (via DirectConnect)

Comment: Have you tried running the code _outside_ of Lambda, to see whether the problem is on the database-end?

Comment: I have confirmed the connection with psql from the same VPC instance

Answer (score 1):

You get that error when the server wants to use SCRAM password hashing, but the client is too old to support it.  Upgrade the client so it links to a newer libpq, or go back to using md5 for the password hashing on the server.